# Form1_KeyDown NOT WORKING

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Contains(e.KeyCode))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(e.KeyCode);
        listBox1.Refresh();
        timer1.Interval -= 10;
        difficultyProgessbar.Value = 800 - timer1.Interval;
        stats.update(true);
    }
    else
    {
        stats.update(false);
    }

    correctLabel.Text = stats.correct.ToString();
    missedLabel.Text = stats.missed.ToString();
    totalLabel.Text = stats.total.ToString();
    accuracyLabel.Text = stats.accuracy.ToString();

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Add a random key to Listbox
    listBox1.Items.Add((Keys)random.Next(65, 90));
    Application.DoEvents();
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 7)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Game Over");
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

When I run my application, `timer1_Tick` event is working fine, however `Form1_KeyDown` event doesn't execute when I press any key.
Is something missing? Why `Key_Down` event never fires?
Thanks

Comment: Is your Forms KeyPreview Property set to true?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1298733/2179864

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keydown fires in the Control with Focus.
To receive it at the Form level, you need to set the property
`this.KeyPreview = True;` on the Form.

[Form.KeyPreview Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview)