# Why KeyDown event wont fire?

Tags: c#

My original intention in to make enter event for text box to run btnOK_Click event, but after several try I can't make it happen, so I tried another way and try KeyPress for any key but still didn't work, so I made these two simple code, but it still didn't work either;

```
    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //enter key is down
            //btnOK_Click(this, e);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("My message here");
        }
    }
    private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            //enter key is down
            //btnOK_Click(this, e);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(((char)Keys.Return).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion? I read some similar questions and they said to set the `IsInputKey` property to true but I can't find it anywhere. I use Visual Studio 2008

Comment: IsInputKey is in [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298640/c-sharp-trying-to-capture-the-keydown-event-on-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Options :
1) Use Key Up Event As

```
public void txt_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                btnOK_Click(sender, e); // or btn.PerformClick();
                return;               
            }
        }
```

2) Make BtnOK the AcceptButton of the form. (Note : this will be for all textboxes in your form)

```
this.AcceptButton = btnOK;
```

Comment: `KeyUp` works! I wonder why `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` won't work :/ Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking to something like this

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)//should be replaced with enter
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

NOTE: the code above is on the `KeyDown` instead of the `KeyPress`

This code should work, assuming you are using winforms

Answer (score 0):

use Escape key instead of return key:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                btnOK_Click(sender, e);
                MessageBox.Show("My message here");
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                btnOK_Click(sender, e);
                MessageBox.Show(((char)Keys.Escape).ToString());
            }
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

also you can check both keys in KeyDown event.
you can also use

```
btnOK.PerformClick();
```

instead of

```
btnOK_Click(sender, e);
```

Comment: I tried `btnOK.PerformClick();` and `Keys.Escape` but still the same