# Using of left/right keyboard button

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, keyboard, keycode

I'm trying to call function with left and right buttons on keyboard, but not sure how to do it proper way.

In result of this attempt, pressing on left/right keyboard keys just switches between GUI elements usual way, and does not works for given functions. Not sure what is wrong here:

```
   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
       {
          func1();
       }
       else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
       {
          func2();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Have you enabled KeyPreview on your form?

Comment: I guess that's because you not handling event. Does the breakpoint hits while debugging? I think [keyprieview property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to enabling keypreview as mentioned in some comments would be to override the ProcessCmdKey Method.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Right)
    {
      func1();
      return true;
    }
    else if (keyData == Keys.Left)
    {
      func2();
      return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Please see [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Setting `KeyPreview` to `true` is not always enough, the `KeyDown` handler of the `Form` still won't be called if e.g. a `Button` has the focus. `ProcessCmdKey` always gets called.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have works correctly, you're just not allowed to press anything beforehand. I think you're looking for a general keydown as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298640/c-sharp-trying-to-capture-the-keydown-event-on-a-form)